# Adding files into Zip and sending them via Mail issues C#

Tags: c#, .net, zip, content-type

I have created a method that collect every file in a folder and then inserts them into a zip file. The zip file is then sent via mail to a customer. My problem is that I can send a mail message with the zip file attached without any problems, But if another user generates the zip file and sends it, it will look like this.

[image]

I had the same issue when trying to attach excel files to a mail message. But i found out that you have to set a ContentType of the files you attach. And after adding this line:                         `ContentType ct = new ContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");`  for the excel files it worked.

My problem is that i am trying to attach a zip file now, i am using this line: `ContentType ct = new ContentType("application/zip"); but this doesnt work. I am using **DotNetZipLib-DevKit-v1.9** to add files into a zip file.

this is my code:

```
public void SendMailedFilesVallensbaek()
        {
            string[] vallensbeakFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(vallensbaekFiles);
            if (vallensbeakFileNames.Count() > 0)
            {
                ContentType ct = new ContentType("application/zip");
                string zipFile = vallensbaekFiles+@"\someZipFile.zip";
                using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    foreach (string file in vallensbeakFileNames)
                    {
                            zip.AddFile(file);
                    }

                    zip.Save(zipFile);
                }
                using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("ares"))
                {
                    using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
                    {
                        msg.From = new MailAddress("system@mail.dk");
                        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("lmy@mail.dk "));
                        msg.Subject = "IBM PUDO";
                        msg.Body = "Best Regards";
                        msg.Body += "<br/>";
                        msg.Body += "me";
                        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(zipFile, ct);
                        msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                        //foreach (string file in sentFiles)
                        //{
                        //    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(file, ct);
                        //    msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                        //}

                        client.Send(msg);
                        client.Dispose();
                        msg.Dispose();
                        ct = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Calling `Dispose` inside the using is not necessary.  The using block will call it automatically.

Comment: Try setting the MIME Header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip;` on the `attachment`. This may be to do with how Outlook handles attachments.

Comment: how am i supposed to do that in a windows form application ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the zip file is created in your local folder or not
and your local folder is able to access by ASP.NET users.

Comment: I can send a mail message with the zip file attached without any problems, But if another user generates the zip file and sends it, it will look like this.

Comment: I suggest you use [IonicZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), this lib is easy and you need not to fill Content-type of your file. By the way, you should check the name of files containing special characters or not.

Comment: i am using IconicZip and thanks for the heads up on the filename and special characters. It seems that the problems was the name vallensbæk, the special character **Æ** was the problem.